# Source of "gsed: can't read : No such file or directory"?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have a Bash script that performs a simple substitution on OS X. Here's the reduced case:

```bash
mkdir vs2005-dynamic
cp cryptdll.vcproj cryptest.sln cryptest.vcproj cryptlib.vcproj dlltest.vcproj vs2005-dynamic/
cd vs2005-dynamic
...

SED=/opt/local/bin/gsed
SEDOPTS=(-i "")
...

PROJ_FILES=($(find $PWD -name "*.vcproj"))
for pf in "${PROJ_FILES[@]}"; do
  "$SED" "${SEDOPTS[@]}" -e 's|RuntimeLibrary="0"|RuntimeLibrary="2"|g' "$pf"
  "$SED" "${SEDOPTS[@]}" -e 's|RuntimeLibrary="1"|RuntimeLibrary="3"|g' "$pf"
done
```

When I run it with `bash -x` it prints eight errors. I can't figure out where the errors are coming from. Searching for the error [provides one hit](http://www.google.com/search?q="gsed%3A+can't+read+%3A+No+such+file+or+directory"), but I don't quite see the solution.

Where is *"gsed: can't read : No such file or directory"* coming from?

---

Below, `<full path>` is `/Users/<username>/<project name>/vs2005-dynamic/`. There are no spaces in the pathname.

```
+ /opt/local/bin/gsed -i '' -e 's|RuntimeLibrary="0"|RuntimeLibrary="2"|g' <full path>/cryptdll.vcproj
/opt/local/bin/gsed: can't read : No such file or directory
+ /opt/local/bin/gsed -i '' -e 's|RuntimeLibrary="1"|RuntimeLibrary="3"|g' <full path>/cryptdll.vcproj
/opt/local/bin/gsed: can't read : No such file or directory
+ for pf in '"${PROJ_FILES[@]}"'
+ /opt/local/bin/gsed -i '' -e 's|RuntimeLibrary="0"|RuntimeLibrary="2"|g' <full path>/cryptest.vcproj
/opt/local/bin/gsed: can't read : No such file or directory
+ /opt/local/bin/gsed -i '' -e 's|RuntimeLibrary="1"|RuntimeLibrary="3"|g' <full path>/cryptest.vcproj
/opt/local/bin/gsed: can't read : No such file or directory
+ for pf in '"${PROJ_FILES[@]}"'
+ /opt/local/bin/gsed -i '' -e 's|RuntimeLibrary="0"|RuntimeLibrary="2"|g' <full path>/cryptlib.vcproj
/opt/local/bin/gsed: can't read : No such file or directory
+ /opt/local/bin/gsed -i '' -e 's|RuntimeLibrary="1"|RuntimeLibrary="3"|g' <full path>/cryptlib.vcproj
/opt/local/bin/gsed: can't read : No such file or directory
+ for pf in '"${PROJ_FILES[@]}"'
+ /opt/local/bin/gsed -i '' -e 's|RuntimeLibrary="0"|RuntimeLibrary="2"|g' <full path>/dlltest.vcproj
/opt/local/bin/gsed: can't read : No such file or directory
+ /opt/local/bin/gsed -i '' -e 's|RuntimeLibrary="1"|RuntimeLibrary="3"|g' <full path>/dlltest.vcproj
/opt/local/bin/gsed: can't read : No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does `<full path>` include spaces? if so, the `PROJ_FILES=($(find $PWD -name "*.vcproj"))` construction will split them I think: you might want to try something like `mapfile -t PROJ_FILES < <(find $PWD -name '*.vcproj')` instead

Comment: @steeldriver - My bad; no, the path does not include spaces. I shortened it to make it easier to read and avoid horizontal scrolling. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3):

With gsed you don't need the extra '', only with the default OSX sed.
Try with either:

```
SED=/usr/bin/sed
```

Or:

```
SEDOPTS=(-i)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning the error is caused by the space between `-i` and `""` which instructs `gnu sed` to edit in-place a file named  (nothing) hence the error.

Comment: That was it, thanks. You gotta love `sed` and its nearly [useless error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19242275) (and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25098283), ...).